# .net core Identity, getting specific signup error conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I wish to test/deal with specific error conditions returned from UserManager, eg: registration failed due to username already on file, etc

```
var user = new SiteUser() { UserName = username, Email = RegisterViewModel.Email };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, RegisterViewModel.Password);
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // here I want to test for specific error conditions
    // eg: username already on file, etc
    // how can I do this?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IdentityResult` contains an [`Errors`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/IdentityResult.cs#L29) property, which is of type `IEnumerable<IdentityError>`. [`IdentityError`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/IdentityError.cs) itself contains both a `Code` property and a `Description` property. This means that your `result` variable in your OP has an `Errors` property that describes the specific errors that occurred.

[`IdentityErrorDescriber`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs) is used for generating instances of `IdentityError`. Here's an example from the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs#L127):

```
public virtual IdentityError DuplicateUserName(string userName)
{
    return new IdentityError
    {
        Code = nameof(DuplicateUserName),
        Description = Resources.FormatDuplicateUserName(userName)
    };
}
```

`IdentityErrorDescriber` is injected into the DI system in the same way that `UserManager` is. This means you can take it as a dependency in your controller's construtor (for example) and use it later, like so (assuming `_errorDescriber` has been created and set in your constructor):

```
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // DuplicateUserName(...) requires the UserName itself so it can add it in the
    // Description. We don't care about that so just provide null.
    var duplicateUserNameCode = _errorDescriber.DuplicateUserName(null).Code;

    // Here's another option that's less flexible but removes the need for _errorDescriber.
    // var duplicateUserNameCode = nameof(IdentityErrorDescriber.DuplicateUserName); 

    if (result.Errors.Any(x => x.Code == duplicateUserNameCode))
    {
        // Your code for handling DuplicateUserName.
    }
}
```

There are a number of different ways to get the `Code` value you want to test against and to do the check itself - this is just one example that's fairly safe against customisations you might want to make to the codes and errors themselves.

If you're interested, here's a [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/UserValidator.cs#L76) to the source for where the `DuplicateUserName` error is added to the `IdentityResult` you get back.

I've only talked about `DuplicateUserName` here, but there are other `IdentityErrorDescriber` values for e.g. `InvalidEmail` that you might also want to check for.